# Как остановить бота, так чтобы у пользователя снова появилась кнопка "Запустить бота"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть бот, нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку он вел себя так если бы пользователь перезапустил его или же так как, если бы впервые запустил его.

Как это можно сделать? Вопрос общего характера в документации я ничего не нашел. Но если что делаю бота на Aiogram.

Comment: По-моему никак. Это пользователь должен на своей стороне (в приложении) остановить/выключить бота.

Comment: использовать сохранения состояния пользователя? хранить данные в бд и при необходимости тянуть состояние оттуда

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov причем тут состояния? Каким образом с помощью состояний я могу перезагрузить бота для пользователя?